# Contacting a moderator

Tags: discussion

How do you contact a moderator? We obviously can't send messages. I know they can send messages to users but not the other way around.

I know they are extremely busy, if I could bring something to their attention not posting it in an open forum.

If I need to I will post it here for all to read but it is preferable not to.

Comment: I saw your message. Taking a look.

Comment: Thanks, someone responded mentioning that action was taken.

Comment: I raised the issue again, it got rejected with nothing to support. Have another look: No Action Needed, No Action Needed, Reject, Close, No Action Needed, No Action Needed, No Action Needed, No Action Needed, No Action Needed and on and on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Flags.**
That's your way to privately contact the moderators.
If you want to report something related to a user just flag any post of that user, select 'other' as reason and fill in your message.

If it's not user related just flag something posted by one moderator and do the same as described above.

Comment: As usual, thank you Marius :)